# PHP if statement help - syntax if URL is in specific directory?

Tags: php, cakephp, if-statement

I know how to edit the syntax of my PHP if statements when it relates to a specific page on my website. For example the following code works fine below:

```
<?php
if ($this->here == '/education') {?>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<?php } ?>
```

However, I have a directory of pages that have a url like so:

```
site.com/c/sdflkjasldkjf
```

For all the pages that are in the `/c/` directory, I want to add an `if` statement like the one above so that if any page has a URL in the `/c/` directory it will result in `meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1`

I tried the following but it doesn't appear to work:

```
if ($this->here == '/c/') {?>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<?php } ?>
```

Is there something like a "contains" operator I can use instead of `==`?

Thanks!  Sorry I'm such a Noob - I'm trying to learn! :)

Comment: Look at the many different php string functions, mainly strpos http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 1):

In this case: `strpos()` is the function you're looking for.

```
$test = strpos($this->here, '/c/');
if ($test !== false) {
  // Good to go
}
```

Check out the documentation here:

[Php Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: Thanks! I tried this:

<?php $test = strpos($this->here, '/c/');
   if ($test !== false) {meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"}<?php } ?>

and it gave me Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'name' (T_STRING)

Comment: You're missing an `echo` in there somewhere. { echo 'meta name="view" ... '}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
<?php       $URlstr= "www.google.com/education";
        if (substr_compare(URlstr, "/education",0)) :?>
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <?php endif; ?>
```

you can use built in string function of php engine, in this case we used "[substr_compare](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-compare.php)"
to view code running: http://codepad.org/0MuJcxXC

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get strpos to work. Ended up getting the following to solve the problem:

```
<?php if (mb_substr($this->here, 0, 3 ) === "/c/") {?>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <?php } ?>            

    <?php
```

Thanks for the help though!